# Creating SAML repository registrations dynamically in Spring Security (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have created a sample project which can demonstrate SAML 2 SSO capabilities with saml providers such as Azure AD and Okta.
I was able to configure both of above providers at once in spring configuration by using `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository` and both of them are working as expected.

```
@Bean
protected RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrations() throws Exception {
    RelyingPartyRegistration oktaRegistration = RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation("https://trial-27.okta.com/app/e/sso/saml/metadata").registrationId("okta").build();
    RelyingPartyRegistration azureRegistration = RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation("file:D:\\saml-test-5.xml").registrationId("azure-saml-test").build();
    List<RelyingPartyRegistration> registrationList = new ArrayList<>();
    registrationList.add(oktaRegistration);
    registrationList.add(azureRegistration);
    return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registrationList);
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests(authorize ->
                    authorize.antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            ).saml2Login();

    
    RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver relyingPartyRegistrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(relyingPartyRegistrations());
    Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(relyingPartyRegistrationResolver, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```

I would like to know whether there is any way to create `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository` dynamically once the application fully started. The requirement is to take the SAML metadata file from user in some sort of a form upload and then create `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository` based on it.
The issue is, `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository` is a Spring bean which is used by the Spring security internals. In this case even though we could create new `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository` instances, will Spring security take them dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not create multiple `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository`, you will create your custom implementation of `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository` that accepts adding new entries to it. A simple example:

```java
@Service
public class MyRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository implements RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository {

    private final List<RelyingPartyRegistration> registrations = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository() {
        addDefaultRegistrations();
    }

    private void addDefaultRegistrations() {
        RelyingPartyRegistration oktaRegistration = RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation("https://trial-27.okta.com/app/e/sso/saml/metadata").registrationId("okta").build();
        RelyingPartyRegistration azureRegistration = RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation("file:D:\\saml-test-5.xml").registrationId("azure-saml-test").build();
        add(oktaRegistration);
        add(azureRegistration);
    }

    @Override
    public RelyingPartyRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
        for (RelyingPartyRegistration registration : this.registrations) {
            if (registration.getRegistrationId().equals(registrationId)) {
                return  registration;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void add(RelyingPartyRegistration newRegistration) {
        this.registrations.add(newRegistration);
    }

}
```

And then in a Controller, for example, you can autowire this dependency and add new registrations to it:

```java
@RestController
public class SamlController {

    private final MyRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository repository;

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public void addRegistration(/* receive it somehow */) {
        this.repository.add(theRegistration);
    }

}
```